# python while loop does not terminate

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am writing a program for counting the score of two users. The game ends when either of them scores a ten and the respective player wins.

I wrote the while loop as:

```
while (score1 != 10) or (score2 != 10):
    ...
```

and my program does not terminate.

Here is the code:

```
player1 = input("Enter name for Player1")
player2 = input("Enter name for Player2")
score1=0
score2=0


print ("Score for Player1 is: %d,Score for player2 is :%d" %(score1,score2))

while (score1 != 10) or (score2 != 10):
    player =input("enter name for player")

    if player is player1:
        score1=score1+1
    if player is player2:
        score2=score2+1
    print ("Score for Player1 is: %d,Score for player2 is :%d" %(score1,score2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want

```
while (score1 != 10) and (score2 != 10):
```

since you want the loop to end as soon as either one of the scores reaches `10`, at which point `score != 10` will be `false` and, consequently, the entire loop-condition will no longer be satisfied.

`(score1 != 10) or (score2 != 10)` would require *both* scores to be `10` before exiting.